# How to get the height of a triangle from three points

Tags: geometry

Having three distinct points as it is possible to obtain the height of the triangle ABC?

What is the distance between the point A to segment BC?

```
a = {4, 2, 1}; b = {1, 0, 1}; c = {1, 2, 0};
```

Comment: @MichaelE2 Does it make sense to close this as a duplicate of a *later* question, even if that question is more encompassing?

Comment: @Feyre I guess it's up to the community.  A foolish consistency...and all that.  Of course, this one allows many silly variants, such as `2 Area@Triangle@{a, b, c}/RegionMeasure@Line@{b, c}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
BC = c - b; BA = a - c;

h = N[Norm[Cross[BC, BA]]/Norm[BC]]
```

> 3.1305

Answer (score 8):

You could use [`RegionDistance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionDistance.html),

```
a = {4, 2, 1}; b = {1, 0, 1}; c = {1, 2, 0};
RegionDistance[InfiniteLine[{b, c}], a]
N@%
(* 7/Sqrt[5] *)
(* 3.1305 *)
```

**edit**: Using `InfiniteLine` instead of `Line`, because for obtuse triangles the [altitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altitude_(triangle)) from point $a$ will not intersect with the line segment $\overline{bc}$.

Or you could work out the trig equations yourself, and use [`VectorAngle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VectorAngle.html) to arrive at

```
Norm[b-a] Sin[VectorAngle[b-c, b-a]]
```

which gives the same answer.

Comment: Two options very good

Comment: Might want to use `InfiniteLine` instead of `Line` in general.

Comment: @MichaelE2 - thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 6):

Just for fun, other answers being more practical, you can use Heron's formula
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula

```
fn[a_, b_, c_] := Module[{area, ab, bc, ca, s},
  ab = Norm[a - b];
  bc = Norm[b - c];
  ca = Norm[c - a];
  s = (ab + bc + ca)/2;
  area = Sqrt[s (s - ab) (s - bc) (s - ca)];
  2 area/bc]
With[{a = {4, 2, 1}, b = {1, 0, 1}, c = {1, 2, 0}},
  fn[a, b, c]] // FullSimplify
% // N
(* 7/Sqrt[5] *)
(* 3.1305 *)
```

Answer (score 4):

Let's ask `FormulaData`. These should suffice (there are not that many anyways :( ):

```
Flatten@{FormulaData["TriangleAreaSSS"], FormulaData["TriangleAreaBH"]} // TeXForm
```

(I started looking for something involving heights: `FormulaLookup["TriangleHeight"]` gave `{"TriangleAreaBH"}` which I noted involved `Areas` which I didn't have yet, so I added "TriangleAreaSSS").

$$\left\{\text{s}=\frac{1}{2} (\text{a}+\text{b}+\text{c}),\text{A}=\sqrt{\text{s} (\text{s}-\text{a})
   (\text{s}-\text{b}) (\text{s}-\text{c})},\text{A}=\frac{\text{b} \text{h}}{2}\right\}$$

```
a = {4, 2, 1}; b = {1, 0, 1}; c = {1, 2, 0};

quantityRename = QuantityVariable[n_, q_] :> Symbol[n <> q];
sides = {aLength -> Norm[b - a], 
   bLength -> Norm[c - b](*height is on b, aka BC, *b*ase*), 
   cLength -> Norm[a - c]};

hHeight /. (
   Solve[Flatten@{FormulaData["TriangleAreaSSS"], 
        FormulaData["TriangleAreaBH"]},
      {QuantityVariable["A","Area"], QuantityVariable["h","Height"], 
       QuantityVariable["s","Length"]}] /. quantityRename
    /. sides) // Simplify
```

> {7/Sqrt[5]}
>
> {3.1305}

It would be nice if there where a formula for the side-lengths given vertex coordinates. I had to get that in there manually.

It's also a bit unfortunate that your variables are called `a, b, c` like those in the formulas.